# How can I color this frame/border of my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I wanted to make a `TextEditor` and tried to change some colors. But I still have difficulties changing the color of the `JFrame` of the `JTextArea` (I mean this white border) and also don't know how I can make this text area so that it always changes the size to the selected JFrame size.

[TextEditorPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emdWn.png)

[TextEditorPicture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qbtm.png)

```
public class TextEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    JTextArea textArea;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JLabel fontLabel;
    JSpinner fontSizeSpinner;
    JButton fontColorButton;
    JComboBox fontBox;
    
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu fileMenu;
    JMenuItem openItem;
    JMenuItem saveItem;
    JMenuItem exitItem;
    
    
    TextEditor(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("TextEditor");
        this.setSize(500,500);

        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,0));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        
        
        //Text Area
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setVisible(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("SF Mono Regular 11", Font.PLAIN,20));
        textArea.setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        textArea.setForeground(Color.decode("#eaeaea"));
        
        //Scroll Panel Sidebar
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,0));
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        
        //Font Text
        fontLabel = new JLabel("Font: ");
        fontLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#eaeaea"));
        
        //Font Size Spinner
        fontSizeSpinner = new JSpinner();
        fontSizeSpinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,25));
        fontSizeSpinner.setValue(20);
        fontSizeSpinner.getEditor().getComponent(0).setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        fontSizeSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                textArea.setFont(new Font("SF Mono Regular 11",Font.PLAIN,(int) fontSizeSpinner.getValue()));
                textArea.setSelectedTextColor(Color.white);
        
                
            }
            
        });

                    
        

        
        
        fontColorButton = new JButton("Color");
        fontColorButton.setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        fontColorButton.setOpaque(true);
        fontColorButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        fontColorButton.addActionListener(this);
        fontColorButton.setForeground(Color.decode("#eaeaea"));
        
        String[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    
        
        //Font Change Box
        fontBox = new JComboBox(fonts);
        fontBox.addActionListener(this);
        
        fontBox.setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        fontBox.setForeground(Color.green);
        fontBox.setOpaque(true);
        fontBox.setEditable(true);
        fontBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));
        ((JTextField) fontBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setBackground(Color.decode("#252025"));

        fontBox.setSelectedItem("SF Mono Regular 11");
        
        //Menubar
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        
        openItem.addActionListener(this);
        saveItem.addActionListener(this);
        exitItem.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        this.add(fontLabel);
        this.add(fontSizeSpinner);
        this.add(fontColorButton);
        this.add(fontBox);
        this.add(scrollPane);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource() == fontColorButton) {
            JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
            Color color = colorChooser.showDialog(null, "Color", Color.white);
            
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==fontBox) {
            textArea.setFont(new Font((String)fontBox.getSelectedItem(),Font.PLAIN,textArea.getFont().getSize()));
        }
        
        //Open
        if(e.getSource()==openItem) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt");
            fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            
            int response = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(response==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                Scanner fileIn = null;
                
                
                try {
                fileIn = new Scanner(file);
                if(file.isFile()) {
                    while(fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = fileIn.nextLine()+"\n";
                        textArea.append(line);
                        
                    }
                }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    fileIn.close();
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        //Save
        if(e.getSource()==saveItem) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            
            int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(response==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file;
                PrintWriter fileOut = null;
                
                file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    fileOut = new PrintWriter(file);
                    fileOut.println(textArea.getText());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    fileOut.close();
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Exit
        if(e.getSource()==exitItem) {
            System.exit(0);
    
}
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Provide a basic drawing or ASCII art of how the GUI should appear at the minimum size and if resizable, with more width and height added. There are multiple errors in the code seen above, but if you will explain clearly (with pictures) how the GUI should look, I (or others) might be willing to give example code on how to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple layouts.  FlowLayout alone is not sufficient.

The center component of a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) will always stretch to fill the container’s space.

Remember that you can put panels inside panels.  Put your font and color labels/fields in a JPanel that uses a FlowLayout, then put that JPanel in the [NORTH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#NORTH) area of a JPanel that uses a BorderLayout.  Your JScrollPane belongs in the center of that same BorderLayout.

Remove all calls to setPreferredSize, setMinimumSize, and setMaximumSize.  They are intefering with a layout manager’s ability to properly arrange things.  All components have a useful preferred size when they are created.

To set the size of your JScrollPane, use the [setRows](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows(int)) and [setColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns(int)) methods of JTextArea.  The JScrollPane parent will consult its [Scrollable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) view (that is, the JTextArea) to determine its preferred size.